# retrieve data from database using php code

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to retrieve data from the database (list of products) but I have a blank page when I execute the code.

```
<?php


$DB_HOST = "@@@";
$DB_NAME = "@@@";
$DB_PASS = "@@@";
$DB_USER = "@@@";


$db_obj = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);
if($db_obj->connect_errno > 0) {
  die('Connection failed [' . $db_obj->connect_error . ']');
}

if($db_obj->connect_errno > 0){
    die('Unable to connect [' . $db_obj->connect_errno . ']');
}


?>



<html>
<head>
<title>List of products</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php


$query="SELECT * FROM product"; 
$result_obj = $db_obj->query($query);
$row=mysql_fetch_row($result);

echo $row;




?>

</body>
</html>
```

I am doing it right? where is the problem exactly? is the problem can be from the server side?

new try:

```
<?php
// session_start();
// require("mysqli.php"); 

$DB_HOST = "webdev.cs.kent.edu";
$DB_NAME = "ralsuhai";
$DB_PASS = "810646396";
$DB_USER = "ralsuhai";


$db_obj = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);
if($db_obj->connect_errno > 0) {
  die('Connection failed [' . $db_obj->connect_error . ']');
}

if($db_obj->connect_errno > 0){
    die('Unable to connect [' . $db_obj->connect_errno . ']');
}


?>



<html>
<head>
<title>List of products</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php


$query="SELECT * FROM product"; 
$result_obj = $db_obj->query($query);
//first try
//while($row=$result_obj->fetch_row() )
//{
  //   var_dump($row);
 //}

 //second try
//$res = array();
//while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
//{
  //$res[] = $row;
//}
//print_r($res);




?>
<table><tr><th>Product Id</th><th>Name</th><th>Price</th></tr>
<?php
$result_obj = $db_obj->query($query);
while($row=$result_obj->fetch_row() )
{ ?>
    <tr>
     <td><?=implode('</td><td>',$row)?></td>
    </tr>
<?php
 }
?>
</table>
<?php










?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are mixing up `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*` functions.

Comment: what is the different between both of them?

Comment: Difference is that they are both _different_

Comment: @user3483167 first off, they can't cooperate. And `mysqli_` supports prepared statements and object-oriented approach, while `mysql_` cannot.

Comment: What Shankar meant by that is, those two functions do not mix. @user3483167

Comment: The mistakes. 1) `mysql_fetch_row` which should be `mysqli_fetch_row` and 2) `$result_obj = $db_obj->query($query); $row=mysql_fetch_row($result);` your assigning `$result_obj` yet retrieving with `$result` which should be `$row=mysqli_fetch_row($result_obj);` 3) You need to use a `while` loop and choose the row you wish to show, not just `echo $row;` @user3483167 I.e.: `echo $row['column_name'];` you also could use `mysqli_fetch_array()` instead or `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`.

Comment: Got it my teacher, thank you! I am still learning :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a couple problems here. First is, the variable `$db_obj` is a mysqli object and your trying to use the mysql_fetch row function on it. That won't work, next even if it did work, $row would be an array.try this...

```
?>
<table><tr><th>Product Id</th><th>Name</th><th>Price</th></tr>
<?php
$result_obj = $db_obj->query($query);
while($row=$result_obj->fetch_row() )
{ ?>
    <tr>
     <td><?php echo implode('</td><td>',$row); ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php
 }
?>
</table>
<?php
```

this should dump each row returned by the query and you can see what's going on. Note that the result from $db_obj->query($query) is an object. This should print a table with your data.

Comment: when I applied this code I got the following:
"array(3) { [0]=> string(10) "prod_99004" [1]=> string(14) "Tennis Racquet" [2]=> string(5) "95.85" } array(3) { [0]=> string(10) "prod_99007" [1]=> string(12) "Tennis Shoes" [2]=> string(5) "75.95" } array(3) { [0]=> string(10) "prod_99008" [1]=> string(12) "Tennis Balls" [2]=> string(4) "3.85" } array(3) { [0]=> string(10) "prod_99009" [1]=> string(14) "Tennis T-shirt" [2]=> string(5) "15.85" }"

Comment: perfect. That's what should be expected, now do as you wish with the data... What are you trying to do anyways?

Comment: all of the information or just the name or name and price?

Comment: all the information in the product table is the data base.

Comment: that should print all the data out in a table.

Comment: the data did not appear with me. I do not know why and I am asking myself the same qustion each time a write and test a code, is there a problem with server that I am using? is it not allowing me to retrive the data?

Comment: The fact you got the data from the var_dump as you posted in the comment here means there is nothing wrong with the server. It is your code.

Comment: Aha got it, so maybe there is a problem with the connection? or it fine since we got the data with the var_dump

Comment: No... it's your code, not the connection not the server. Your code.

Comment: That should work, only thing I can think is you don't have short tags enabled on the server. see new edit.

Comment: no data is retrieved, I just have the table header Product Id name price

Comment: I was making one of the function as a comment :D

Comment: Great, glad you got it :) Feel free to accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
   $DB_HOST = "@@@";
   $DB_NAME = "@@@";
   $DB_PASS = "@@@";
   $DB_USER = "@@@";

   $db_obj = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);
   if($db_obj->connect_errno) {
   die('Connection failed [' . $db_obj->connect_error . ']');
   }
?>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>List of products</title>
      </head>
      <body>
      <?php
         $query="SELECT * FROM product";
         $result_obj = $db_obj->query($query);
         $row=$result_obj->fetch_assoc();
         print_r($row);
      ?>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: if I want to update a table in the database, I can use the following:

<?php
$query="UPDATE admin SET password=npassword"; 

{ ?>
    
     <?php echo "your password has been updated!"  ?>
    
<?php
 }
?>

Comment: <?php $query="UPDATE admin SET password=npassword WHERE user_id=2";
$query = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
?>